# need to change date format in Varchar column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have DOB `varchar` column which contains date value. I am getting dates in `mm/dd//yyyy` format.
I have to change format of all these values to `yyyymmdd` format in DOB column. I can't use `datetime` datatype for DOB column as per customer’s demand.

Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Does the customer have any clue what they're talking about? You may consider educating them.

Comment: ...instead of just doing the wrong thing because, you know, they said so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename
  SET DOB = CONVERT(CHAR(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, DOB, 101), 112);
```

Of course there is no guarantee that all of the data in there right now is valid m/d/y data. Someone could have entered d/m/y, or something that is entirely not a date at all.

You can get close by fixing any rows that come back from this query:

```
SELECT DOB FROM dbo.tablename WHERE ISDATE(DOB) = 0;
```

Of course this won't identify any rows where someone entered `09/05/2013` and meant May 9th, not September 5th.

This also won't prevent future strings from being entered that are not valid dates (or not the dates that the user who entered them expected them to represent).

Strongly consider having your customer read these posts. We have date-related data types for a reason.

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I've always found the `DATE` datatype to be quite lovely for storing dates. Almost as if it was built for that very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do .....

```
SELECT CAST( YEAR(DOB_Column) AS VARCHAR(4)) +  
       CAST( LPAD(MONTH(DOB_Column),2,0) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
       CAST( LPAD(DAY(DOB_Column),2,0) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS MyDate 
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This will yield, for e.g. January 1st, `201411` which is not a date at all. For January 21, it will yield `2014121`.

Comment: I removed my comment because I keep forgetting that SQL Server will automatically convert '01/21/2014' to date. Worked to long with ORACLE where you had to convert strings to date.

Comment: `Msg 195 : LPAD() is not a recognized built-in function name.` Besides, this is a really convoluted way to format a date as a string in a format that's already supported natively.

Comment: Aaron, I looked over your answer above and I agree. It is much simpler to manipulate the DateTime format with the built in functions than the way i was mentioning. For my solution to work I would have to pad single digits with a zero. (I thought LPAD was a valid function in SQL server, I was wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/01/2012'), 112)
```

but I was typing too slow. So another alternative would be, but this is not a robust solution because it relies on formatting to be the same.

```
 DECLARE @MyDate VARCHAR(12) = '12/25/2012';
 SELECT SUBSTRING(@MyDate, 7, 4) + SUBSTRING(@MyDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(@MyDate, 0, 3)
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is exactly why this solution is poor, it will just parse text without verifying it to be correct date and format.